# Reducing neo4j transaction finish time

Tags: transactions, neo4j, database-performance

What all factors does a time needed for `transaction.finish()` in neo4j depends on?

I'm using neo4j for Facebook graph building. Each `Node` has list of on average 500 objects of a class containing:

```
4 Strings of max length 20 chars
1 doubles 
1 long
1 Date
1 boolean
```

and `Relationship` has list of on average 20 such objects.

There are about 3,00,000 nodes and same order of total Relationships.

For such nodes, if I update for around 300 nodes, I found it's update takes about 50 sec. and transaction time around 10 min. Memory utilization is about 2.5GB, Processor: dual core 2.93GHz.

This transaction finish time looks too high.

Can I get any suggestions on how to reduce the transaction finishing time?

**EDIT:**

I found one such heavy Node whose all properties combined together as string gave a string of length `15650993` characters.

Answer (score 1):

In tx.finish() the changes are written to the logical log and forced down to disk. Then the changes are applied to the database store files, which most likely will not force anything down to disk, in favor of updating the memory mapped portions of those files. Except now and then the logical log gets rotated and all changes to the database store files are forced to disk as well.

Regarding your big string property, I wouldn't expect even 15Mb to be nearly as slow as that. Have you made any profiling of it?